# Como interpreto este Queue

Tags: javascript

Hola soy nuevo en el mundo de la programacion, para ponerlos en contexto estoy estudiando este ejercicio en VS CODE y una vez terminado se tiene que correr el test, mi pregunta es en que momento se declaro la Queue, de donde salio la enqueue, la dequeue y el size, es decir son palabras reservadas, son metodos?

```
// test const { Queue } = require("../DS");

function henryParking(arr) {
  // Tu código aquí:
  let henryParkin = new Queue(); //cola
  for(let i =0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] !== "OUT") {
      henryParkin.enqueue(arr[i]); // poner en cola
    } else {
      henryParkin.dequeue() //sacar de la cola
    }
  }
  if(henryParkin.size()<=0) return false;
   return henryParkin;
}
```

Comment: ¿Dónde se declaró? No es posible saberlo sin ver el código completo. `enqueue`, `dequeue` y `size` son métodos de clase `Queue`.

Comment: Revisaste la documentación?

Comment: Sin ver el código completo no es posible saberlo.

Comment: La primera línea de código (comentada) está importando la clase Queue del fichero `../DS.js` o `../DS/index.js`

Comment: Tienen razon son métodos del prototipo Queue que ya estan definidos en el fichero DS.js. Muchas gracias